# Get a specific div area in a page by url

Tags: javascript, drupal, mobile

I have a form in a page on a Drupal site. I wondered if it was possible to via URL deliver just the div/box that the form resides in, extracted from the page. E.g. without header / footer and other page elements.

Comment: What do you mean "via URL"?

Comment: I need to trigger how the page will be returned depending on the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make HTML file, get the form page using AJAX (jQuery/JS), parse `responseText` to get only desired `<div>` and `document.write()` it. 
Using URL http://somepage.com/yourHtmlFile.htm you will receive only that `<div>`.

Comment: As the OP mentions Drupal, I think your method will not work. each Drupal-made form has a form build ID as a hidden input field so you will not be able to submit the form. It will trigger a "validation failed" error.

Comment: You're partially right, I guess "validation failed" error will occur, if he try to submit thit form to base URL but... he didn't mention, that he want to do it. AFAIK, he just wanted to "trigger how the page will be returned depending on the request", so my solution should work. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal Webforms, edit the form in question. Click the "webform" tab. Next, click the "Form Setting" sub menu. Then, click the "Advanced" collapsible div at the bottom of the page. Finally, check the "make available as block" check box. This makes the form (and only the form) available as a block in which you can do whatever you like with.

Comment: thanks, I will also try this.